# Doubt in passing in the Riemann mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I have a question, maybe silly in the passage marked in red. I understood everything up to this part. Why does $H'(0) > 0$ imply $e^{i \theta} = 1$? Is the Schwarz Lemma being used?

Comment: The derivative of $H(z)$ is the constant function $e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  if I understood correctly, just note that $|H'(z)| = 1$, but $H$ has positive derivative in $0$ because $F$ and $G$ have positive derivatives in zero. Then $e^{i \theta}=H'(0) = |H'(0)| = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $H=F \circ G^{-1}$ we get with the chain rule and the rule for the derivative of $G^{-1}$ that

$$ H'(0)= \frac{F'(z_0)}{G'(z_0)}.$$

Since $F'(z_0), G'(z_0)>0$, it follows that $H'(0)>0$.

From $H(z)=e^{i \theta}z$,  we get $H'(0)=e^{i \theta}.$

Furthermore we have: $e^{i \theta}>0 \iff e^{i \theta}=1.$